# Function Calling Execution in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code.

```
for(var i = 0; i< bookmarks.length; i++){
        (function(i) {
            parseArticle(i,bookmark_id,bookmark_url,function(err,result){
                console.log("Success");
            });

        })(i);

}   


function parseArticle(i,bookmark_id,bookmark_url,callback) {
            diffbot.article({uri: url}, function(err, response) {
                console.log("Diffbot is" );
            });
            console.log("Parse Article" );
    callback(null,i);
};
```

Now output is coming like this

**Parse Article**

**Sucess**

**Diffbot is**

I want to execute function in this way so output will be like

**Diffbot**

**Parse Article**

**Sucess**

Can anybody tell me what is exact problem here and how to resolve that

Thanks

Comment: ok. For now can you tell me what is the solution for that, And from where i can learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn what an asynchronous function and its completion callback are. When you understand that, you will understand why "Parse Article" is printed first and will have a better idea how you should structure your code. In a nutshell, an asynchronous functions starts an operation (which usually involves timers or networking or I/O of some kind) and the rest of your code continues to execute. Then, some time LATER, the asynchronous operation completes and the completion callback is called.

The key to using an asynchronous operation is that ALL activity that you want to happen after the asynchronous operation and all activity that you want to use the result of the asynchronous activity MUST be inside the callback that indicates the completion of the async activity.

In your particular case, you can achieve the desired output by putting things into the `diffbot.article` callback.  This should generate this log:

```
Diffbot
Parse Article
Sucess

function parseArticle(i,bookmark_id,bookmark_url,callback) {
      diffbot.article({uri: url}, function(err, response) {
            // put everything in here that should occur after the async
            // operation is done
            console.log("Diffbot is" );
            console.log("Parse Article" );
            callback(null,i);
      });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do some research into `asynchronous` programming with `callbacks`.

```
for(var i = 0; i< bookmarks.length; i++){
  parseArticle(i,bookmark_id,bookmark_url,function(err,result){
    console.log("Success");
  });
}   

function parseArticle(i,bookmark_id,bookmark_url,callback) {
  diffbot.article({uri: url}, function(err, response) {
    console.log("Diffbot is");
    console.log("Parse Article");
    callback(null, i); // this will call the success
  });
}
```

try reading [this](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/).